# Parent window to iframe messaging not working

Tags: javascript, iframe, window, message, postmessage

I have a window, which is the parent. Then there is an iframe which is inside this window.
In the parent window, I am making an ajax call. After I receive data from the call, I need to post the data to the child iframe.

In the child iframe, I have registered the call as given below -

```
function Mymessage() {
    console.log("Received message from parent window");
}
window.addEventListener("message", Mymessage, false);
```

In the parent, on success of ajax call, I am sending the data to child iframe as given below -

```
window.postMessage(mydata, '*');
```

Problem - I have been debugging, reading about it. But not working. The "Mymessage" function does not get called at all. Why?

When I put debug point on window.postmessage, it hits it. But when I try to enter inside it, it just goes to next line. Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

Please try bellow:

```
window.onload = function() {
    (window.addEventListener && window.addEventListener('message', Mymessage, false) // FF,SA,CH,OP,IE9+
                    || window.attachEvent && window.attachEvent('onmessage', Mymessage)); // IE8 
}
```